# Textarea issue in IE7

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4

In a textarea, I am entering a single character on a line, and pressing enter, and continuing to do this until, after 334 characters, I am unable to enter any more characters. This limit occurs only in IE7.

I cannot figure it out, why is this happening ?

The following is the View code.

```
@Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.Description,
    new { @id = "txtAreaDescription",
          @class = "expand12-200",
          @onkeypress = "return maxLength(this,'500');",
          @onpaste = "return maxLengthPaste(this,'500');"
    })
```

Comment: Have you set a `maxlength` value?

Comment: Dis younchangenthe maxrows or maxchars atrributes? Look http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/56392/How-to-Limit-the-Number-of-Lines-and-Characters-in

Comment: @TiesonT. Textarea does not support maxlength. Have to write custom javascript to restrict the number of characters.

Comment: Have edited the question for some reference. Its strange, because it is only at one location where the problem exists. There are many other  similar implementations done without any problem

Comment: @ravi139 in IE < 10, no, but it is an HTML5-defined attribute. Regardless, you are correct that it isn't relevant to the problem at hand.

Comment: do you want to add your Javascript code for the function maxLength? also, copy and paste your text into notepad++(or similar) and do a character count. you may find that your carriage-returns are counted as characters.

Comment: @kolin : i have added javascript code for maxlength for both while typing and copy paste scenario.